# Reliable way to check that wireguard app is installed on windows?

Tags: windows, installation, wireguard

I need to check whether the [WireGuard](https://www.wireguard.com/install/) app is installed on windows. I could just check for `C:\program files\Wireguard\Wireguard.exe` but this installation directory could change.

Is there a more reliable way to check whether the app is installed, independent of the installation directory? perhaps the existence of some kind of registry key or so?

Thanks

Comment: Control Panel>Programs and features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution

`Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize`

Then look at the results to see if your application is listed.